# Expo SDK 29 FlatList onRefresh not calling

Tags: react-native, react-redux, expo

Using Expo SDK 29 for a react native application.

I would like to use a flat list component. This makes up the entirety of a SafeAreaView component. I make this point as there are lots of issues relating to a flat list inside of a scroll view which this is not.

The flat list shows a list of jobs.

I have added a jobLoading boolean to the redux state to manage when the list should show as refreshing and can confirm that this toggles as expected when firing the actions to fetch the data and the success.

When i add the props to the flat list for onRefresh and refreshing the component seems to work by showing the activity indicator in the UI but does not fire the onRefresh function. I have tried implementing the call in numerous ways but nothing happens. The result is that the activity indicator shows itself and never disappears.

As it's Expo SDK 29 the React Native version is 0.55.4

Anyone have any ideas of what to try. I've spent a couple of hours looking at this trying various things but suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Added the code for reference. Reducer for refreshing sets true when fetchJobs() is dispatched and false when a success or error is recieved. The console log for onRefresh never triggers.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as actions from '../../redux/actions'
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, KeyboardAvoidingView, Dimensions, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import { ApplicationState, JobState, Job } from '../../redux'
import { Button, Form, Input, Item, Text, Icon } from 'native-base'
import { JobListItem } from './jobListItem'
import { StateHandlerMap, compose, lifecycle, withPropsOnChange, withStateHandlers } from 'recompose'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

interface ReduxStateProps {
    jobs: JobState
    refreshing: boolean
    screenOrientation: string
}

interface ReduxDispatchProps {
    fetchJobs: (param?: string) => any
}

export interface DataItem {
    key: string
    data: Job
}

interface ListProps {
    jobList: DataItem[]
}

interface SearchStateProps {
    timer: number | undefined
    searchString: string
}

interface SearchHandlerProps extends StateHandlerMap<SearchStateProps> {
    updateSearch: (searchString: string) => any
    setTimer: (timer: number | undefined) => any
}

type OuterProps = {}
type InnerProps = OuterProps & ReduxStateProps & ReduxDispatchProps & ListProps & SearchStateProps & SearchHandlerProps

const enhance = compose<InnerProps, OuterProps>(
    connect<ReduxStateProps, ReduxDispatchProps, OuterProps, ApplicationState>(
        state => ({
            jobs: state.job,
            refreshing: state.jobLoading,
            screenOrientation: state.screenOrientation
        }),
        dispatch => ({
            fetchJobs: (param?: string) => dispatch(actions.jobs.request({ param }))
        })
    ),
    withPropsOnChange<ListProps, OuterProps & ReduxStateProps & ReduxDispatchProps>(
        ['jobs', 'screenOrientation'],
        props => ({
            jobList: props.jobs && Object.keys(props.jobs).map(job => ({ key: job, data: props.jobs[Number(job)] }))
        })
    ),
    withStateHandlers<SearchStateProps, SearchHandlerProps, OuterProps>(
        {
            timer: undefined,
            searchString: ''
        },
        {
            updateSearch: state => (searchString: string) => ({ searchString }),
            setTimer: state => (timer: number | undefined) => ({ timer })
        }
    ),
    lifecycle<InnerProps, {}>({
        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.fetchJobs()
        }
    })
)

export const JobList = enhance(({ fetchJobs, jobList, refreshing, screenOrientation, searchString, setTimer, timer, updateSearch }) => {

    const onSearchChange = (search: string) => {
        clearTimeout(timer)

        updateSearch(search)

        const timing = setTimeout(() => {
            fetchJobs(search)
        }, 500)

        setTimer(timing)
    }
const onRefresh = () => {
    console.log('requesting refresh')
    fetchJobs()
}

return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1}}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', paddingTop: 3, paddingRight: 3 }}>
            <Form style={{ flex: 1, paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 10 }}>
                <Item>
                    <Input
                        value={searchString}
                        onChangeText={(text: string) => onSearchChange(text)}
                        placeholder='Search' 
                    />
                </Item>
            </Form>
            <Button onPress={() => {fetchJobs(); updateSearch('')}}>
                <Icon name='refresh' />
            </Button>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>

        {refreshing && 
            <View style={styles.refreshContainer}>
                <Text style={{ paddingBottom: 10 }}>Fetching Data</Text>
                <ActivityIndicator />
            </View>
        }
        <FlatList
            keyExtractor={item => item.key} 
            data={jobList}
            renderItem={({ item }) => 
                <JobListItem 
                    screenOrientation={screenOrientation}
                    item={item}
                />
            }
            onRefresh={onRefresh}
            refreshing={refreshing}
        />
    </SafeAreaView>
)
})

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    refreshContainer: {
        height: 60,
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
})
```

Comment: post the relevant code, if the indicator isn't disappearing then you're either not using the `refreshing` prop which is required to implement `onRefresh` or your function is being called but not completing and dispatching the event that is meant to set the `refreshing` prop to false

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue and I'm using expo SDK 30. But my case is a little bit different. The onRefresh function is called everytime I pull, however if I scroll down my list, and scroll back up fast, the loading indicator shows up, but my onRefresh function is not called.

My refreshing prop is set on my reducer, and my onRefresh function dispatches an action that fetches data and set refreshing true and false.

Here is my code:

```
    class NoticiasScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: <Header
              title='Notícias Alego'
              leftComponent={<Image source={require('../../../assets/images/play_grande.png')} style={imageStyle} resizeMode='contain'/>}
            />
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
    this.keyExtractor = this.keyExtractor.bind(this);
    this.renderContent = this.renderContent.bind(this);
    this.navigateToNoticias = this.navigateToNoticias.bind(this);
    this.carregarMaisNoticias = this.carregarMaisNoticias.bind(this);
    this.onRefresh = this.onRefresh.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.carregarNoticias(this.props.pagina);
  }

  renderItem({item}) {
    return (
      <NoticiaListItem noticia={item} abrirNoticia={this.navigateToNoticias} />
    );
  }

  keyExtractor(item) {
    return item.id.toString();
  }

  navigateToNoticias(noticia) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('NoticiasExibir', { id: noticia.id });
  }

  onRefresh() {
    console.log('onRfresh');
    this.props.carregarNoticias(1, true);
  }

  carregarMaisNoticias() {
    const { carregarNoticias, pagina } = this.props;
    carregarNoticias(pagina + 1);
  }

  renderContent() {
    const { noticias, carregandoNoticias, erroNoticias } = this.props;

    if(noticias.length === 0 && carregandoNoticias) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.containerCenter}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={colors.verde}/>
        </View>
      );
    }

    if(erroNoticias) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.containerCenter}>
          <Text style={styles.message}>{erroNoticias}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity hitSlop={hitSlop15}>
            <Text>Recarregar</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )
    }

    return (
      [<TextInput
        style={styles.textInput}
        placeholder='Pesquise'
        key='pesquisa'
        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
      />,
      <FlatList
        data={noticias}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        style={styles.list}
        key='lista'
        onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
        refreshing={carregandoNoticias}
        onEndReached={this.carregarMaisNoticias}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
      />]
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
        <View style={styles.container}>

          {this.renderContent()}
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    noticias: state.intranet.noticias,
    pagina: state.intranet.pagina,
    erroNoticias: state.intranet.erroNoticias,
    carregandoNoticias: state.intranet.carregandoNoticias
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    carregarNoticias: (pagina, recarregar) => dispatch(ActionCreator.carregarNoticias(pagina, recarregar))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NoticiasScreen);
```

No idea what's going on. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I fixed it somehow. I added the onMomentScrollBegin prop to prevent my flatList from rendering twice on Render, and that fixed this issue.

here is what I added:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    ...

    this.onRefresh = this.onRefresh.bind(this);


    this.onMomentumScrollBegin = this.onMomentumScrollBegin.bind(this);

    this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = true; //PUT THIS HERE
  }


 onRefresh() {
    this.props.carregarNoticias(1, true);
  }

  carregarMaisNoticias() {
    if(!this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum){
      const { carregarNoticias, pagina } = this.props;
      carregarNoticias(pagina + 1);
      this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = true;
    }
  }

  onMomentumScrollBegin() {
    this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = false;
  }

render() {
  <OptimizedFlatList
    data={noticias}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
    style={styles.list}
    key='lista'
    onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
    refreshing={carregandoNoticias}
    onMomentumScrollBegin={this.onMomentumScrollBegin} //PUT THIS HERE
    onEndReached={this.carregarMaisNoticias}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
 />
}
```